# React.useEffect: State not updating after axios request

Tags: reactjs, token, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am in the process of trying to convert a class Component into a functional component to leverage the [React.useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [React.useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). The component is making requests to check if a token exists on a server.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Loader, Dimmer, Transition, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { hasBeenVerified } from '../../store/reducers/users/index';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';


function Confirmation({ match, isAccountVerified, hasBeenVerified }) {
  var [token, setToken] = React.useState(null);
  var [duration, setDuration] = React.useState(500);
  var [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = React.useState({});
  var [error, setError] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('token ', token);
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8016/users/confirmation/${setToken(match.params.token)}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          hasBeenVerified();
          setResponseMessage(response.data.msg);
          return;
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response.status === 404) {
          setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
          setError(true);
          return;
        }
        if (error.response.status === 400) {
          setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
          setError(true);
          return;
        }
      });

      return () => {
       setToken(null);
       setResponseMessage({});
       setError(false);
    };
  }, [token, isAccountVerified, hasBeenVerified, setResponseMessage, setError]);
  console.log('token ', token);

  console.log('isAccountVerified ', isAccountVerified);
  console.log('match', match);
  console.log('responseMessage', responseMessage);
  return (
    <div className="login-form">
      <Transition
        visible={isAccountVerified}
        unmountOnHide={true}
        animation="scale"
        duration={duration}
      >
        {!isAccountVerified ? (
          <Dimmer active inverted>
            <Loader />
          </Dimmer>
        ) : (
          <Message success={!error} error={error} header={responseMessage[0]} />
        )}
      </Transition>
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { users } = state;
  const { isAccountVerified } = users;

  return { isAccountVerified };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ hasBeenVerified }, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Confirmation);
```

I have added [values to the dependency array because it is an outside value it depends on](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects). I've also added the cleanup function prescribed as well.

Can anyone offer any insight why it doesn't render at all i.e. success, the different error results?

Comment: I wrote your component a bit better and post it as another answer. also, I leave an upvote for your question for motivation. hope the second answer helps you to write your components better and more readable.

Comment: Dear Antonio, thanks for upvoting me. I guess the first answer was better for this post. the second one just descript the clean code. the first actually, explain the cause of the issue. really thanks. and if it helps you please see please visit my profile and read my bio. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return after an asynchronous call. so definitely your state became `{}`.

Change the `[token, isAccountVerified, hasBeenVerified, setResponseMessage, setError]` to `[]` and it works well.

This array is using for running the useEffect callback function for changing the values of it. you passed the functions?!

Even you destruct the `Component` but never use it. your code is very very noisy to read.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

~~~

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('token ', token);
    axios.get('http://localhost:8016/users/confirmation/${setToken(match.params.token)}')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          hasBeenVerified();
          setResponseMessage(response.data.msg);
          // return;
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response.status === 404) {
          setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
          setError(true);
          // return;
        }
        if (error.response.status === 400) {
          setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
          setError(true);
          // return;
        }
      });

      /* return () => { // this commented part run exactly after asynchronous axios call. you don't need this part.
       setToken(null);
       setResponseMessage({});
       setError(false);
    }; */ 
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain what is making it noisy?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz, Please wait, I'm in a family visit, after this meeting I will send a CodeSandBox for you.

Comment: Of course, by all means! Looking forward to the insight which will hopefully equal to `Antonio Pavicevac-Ortiz === 'better dev'`

Answer (score 1):

I write a common ReactJS code in the following, based on the Airbnb ESLint standard.

- I don't understand why you import `Component` by using the destructuring assignment. it is a function component, so just import `useState` and `useEffect` by destructuring assignment.
- Why you call your API call inside the component. it's not a common way, write it inside another file and import it or use `redux` action dispatching to call your API and get your API data from your redux. both of these ways are common.
- Never write your content inside your JavaScript logical codes. write it in another file and just import it. it means you should separated your URLs paths. just like separating your API calls.
- God shows his mercy, why you do not use this kindness? I mean `async/await`. definitely it makes all codes more readable.
- Use [optional chainging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for nested values like `match.params.token`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Loader, Dimmer, Transition, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { hasBeenVerified } from '../../store/reducers/users';
import { confirmCall } from '[pathTo]/api'; // pseudo code

const Confirmation = ({
  match,
  isAccountVerified,
  hasBeenVerified
}) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(500);
  const [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await confirmCall(match?.param?.token);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        hasBeenVerified();
        setResponseMessage(response.data.msg);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 404) {
        setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
        setError(true);
      }
      if (error.response.status === 400) {
        setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
        setError(true);
      }
    }
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="login-form">
      <Transition
        visible={isAccountVerified}
        unmountOnHide={true}
        animation="scale"
        duration={duration}
      >
        {!isAccountVerified ? (
          <Dimmer active inverted>
            <Loader />
          </Dimmer>
        ) : (
          <Message
            success={!error}
            error={error}
            header={responseMessage[0]}
          />
        )}
      </Transition>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ users: { isAccountVerified } }) => ({
  isAccountVerified
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ hasBeenVerified }, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Confirmation);
```

Comment: Thanks for the 411 and great explanation! Oh by the way the component declaration and destruction was left over declarations when it was a class Component.